# Decomposition of a vector on basis $\vec{q}\times \vec{r}, \vec{p}\times \vec{r},\vec{p}\times \vec{q}$

Tags: vector-analysis, cross-product

How to prove that $\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{p} &\vec{q}  &\vec{r} 
\end{bmatrix}\vec{a}=\left ( \vec{q}\times \vec{r} \right )\left ( \vec{p}.\vec{a} \right )+\left ( \vec{p}\times \vec{r} \right )\left ( \vec{q}.\vec{a} \right )+\left ( \vec{p}\times \vec{q} \right )\left ( \vec{r}.\vec{a} \right )$?

Comment: Write it all out in terms of the coordinates of $p,q,r$ and $a$?

Comment: @ChrisCuster  By coordinates, do you mean $\vec{a}=a_{1}\widehat{i}+a_{2}\widehat{j}+a_{3}\widehat{k}$

Comment: Yes.  $\vec a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ etc.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title into something that reflects the content of the question (the former "multiplication of vectors" was misleding).

Comment: @JeanMarie okay

Answer (score 0):

Here is a derivation. See conventions in a remark below.

The result to be established can be expressed under the form :

$$\tau a = (pu^T+qv^T+rw^T)^T a\tag{*}$$

with notations :

$$\tau:=\det(p,q,r)\tag{1}$$

$$\left\{\eqalign{
u &:= q\times r \cr
v &:= r\times p \cr
w &:= p\times q \cr
}\right.\tag{2}$$

It is easy to see that :

$$\begin{pmatrix} - \ u^T \ - \\ \hline - \ v^T \ - \\ \hline - \  w^T \ - \end{pmatrix}\left( \begin{array}{c|c|c}&&\\p&q&r\\&&\end{array}\right)=\tau I \tag{3}$$

As the inverse is unique, we have therefore as well :

$$\tau I 
=\left( \begin{array}{c|c|c}&&\\p&q&r\\&&\end{array}\right)\begin{pmatrix} - \ u^T \ - \\ \hline - \ v^T \ - \\ \hline - \ w^T \ - \end{pmatrix}= pu^T+qv^T+rw^T\tag{4}$$

(3) and (4) with words : the matrix whose columns are the components of cross products $u,v,w$ is the adjugate of the matrix with column vectors $p,q,r$.

It suffices now to apply the two extreme expressions of (4) to (column) vector $a$, to obtain (*).

**Remark :** Classically, a vector is assimilated to a column vector ; besides, notation $v^T$ means the (T)ranspose of a column vector $v$, i.e., a row vector.
With these notations, for example $v^Tu$ represents a number, dot product of vectors $u$ and $v$, whereas $uv^T$ represents a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: Couldn't understand

Comment: Please say what you don't understand : is it (1), (2), (3) ? .... Is it the matrix row and column notations that you don't understand ? By classical default convention, a vector is assimilated to a are column vector : when you see $V^T$ it means the transpose of a column vector, i.e., a row vector.

Comment: I couldn't understand how the entire answer proves that LHS=RHS of the question

Comment: Should I understand that it is because you haven't seen yet vector and matrices computations ?

Comment: I haven't come across the concept used here yet